# How to pass array in highchart ??

Tags: javascript, php, highcharts

I have just started using highcharts and here I am stuck -

I have 2 array named - `js_platform, js_totalTest` , which I am fetching from the database.

The code to generate chart is -

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <body>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.0.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://code.highcharts.com/modules/exporting.js"> </script>
    <script>
$(function () {
    js_platform = <?php echo json_encode($platform); ?>;
    js_totalTest = <?php echo json_encode($totalTest); ?>;
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'column'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Overall avalibility of testcases on each platform'
            },
            xAxis: {
                categories: js_platform
            },
            yAxis: {
                min: 0,
                title: {
                    text: 'Total fruit consumption'
                },
                stackLabels: {
                    enabled: true,
                    style: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.textColor) || 'gray'
                    }
                }
            },
            legend: {
                align: 'right',
                x: -70,
                verticalAlign: 'top',
                y: 20,
                floating: true,
                backgroundColor: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.legendBackgroundColorSolid) || 'white',
                borderColor: '#CCC',
                borderWidth: 1,
                shadow: false
            },
            tooltip: {
                formatter: function() {
                    return '<b>'+ this.x +'</b><br/>'+
                        this.series.name +': '+ this.y +'<br/>'+
                        'Total: '+ this.point.stackTotal;
                }
            },
            plotOptions: {
                column: {
                    stacking: 'normal',
                    dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: (Highcharts.theme && Highcharts.theme.dataLabelsColor) || 'white',
                        style: {
                            textShadow: '0 0 3px black, 0 0 3px black'
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                name: 'John',
                data: [5, 3, 4, 7, 2]
            }, {
                name: 'Jane',
                data: [2, 2, 3, 2, 1]
            }, {
                name: 'Joe',
                data: [3, 4, 4, 2, 5]
            }]
        });
    });
    </script>

<div id="container" style="min-width: 310px; height: 400px; margin: 0 auto"></div>

</body>
</html>
```

Now for the series I want to send the array values of **js_totalTest**.

Here if i do something like  `**series: [{data: [js_totalTest]}]**` , it does not display anything.

How I can do this ?
Please guide.

Comment: you have to pass series data in json format.

Comment: MM...yes looks like, I just want all the values of js_Toaltest in series. I tired this code but it does not work - 

`var mySeries = [];
    for (var i = 0; i < js_totalTest.length; i++) {
        mySeries.push([js_totalTest[i], js_totalTest[i + 1]]);
        i++
    };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do something like -

```
series: 
    [{
        data:  [<?php echo join($totalTest, ',') ?>]
    }]
```

Refer to the link (http://www.highcharts.com/docs/working-with-data/preprocessing-data-from-a-database)

Answer (score 1):

Try this way like.
Your array `js_totalTest` contains the **data** and **name** values

Loop your array data

```
var arr = [];
for(var i=0;i<js_totalTest.length;i++)
{
    arr[i] = {};
    arr[i]['name'] = '';  //Here push your series name field in your example "John, Jane etc"

    for(var j=0;j<s.length;j++)
    {
            arr_data.push(parseInt(s[j]));
    }
    arr[i]['data'] = parseInt('') ;  // Here push your series data (Eg: 5 ,3 , etc.)
}
```

Pass `arr` in series

```
series: arr
```

Comment: hey i didn't get

`arr[i]['name'] = '';  //Here push your series name field`

`arr[i]['data'] = parseInt('') ;  // Here push your series data`

Comment: i updated my post check.
print your array format and check in what way data is coming.

Comment: @Gowiri the output of `echo json_encode($totalTest);` is like -

**["1","1","4","193","98","218","98","471","9","201","18","144","2","163","30","163","90","84","47","428","397","74","4","1","1","1","979","297","264","418","316","280","6","4","1","1","2","9","2","52","201","80","316","433","691","496","767","610","1","20"]**

Comment: I don't see anything in the output. there is no graph