# Array as Highcharts series isn't working

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

I am having issues trying to pass arrays as parameters in highcharts. 
I am [following](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22904389/how-to-pass-array-in-highchart) - (Gowri's) suggestion but I have not luck with it. As even though the user names (blanked surnames out intentionally) are rendered correctly in my legend the actual values are missed out completely, thus my chart is always empty i.e. no bars...

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqErt.png]

even though the array is populated correctly, and user names appear ok in legend, it is not showing anything

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/iCA60.png]

I have posted a sample on jsfiddle too, but sorry for not rendering properly

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/485vxh9c/) (json2 source included)

HTML:

```
<script src="http://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
<center>
    <div id='searchdiv'></div>
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        setTimeout(function() {
            Chart_Weekly_Trends_Bar('weeklypackagingtrends', 'Passed Approval', ['03/01/2014', '10/01/2014', '17/01/2014', '24/01/2014', '31/01/2014', '07/02/2014', '14/02/2014', '21/02/2014', '28/02/2014', '07/03/2014'], 'Number of Apps', 'No of Apps', ['Andr', 'Ch', 'Gra', 'Gul', 'Hora', 'Jhan', 'Krist', 'Man', 'Mike', 'Phil', 'Tris'], ['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,2', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,2,1', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0'])
        }, 100);
    </script>
```

Javascript:

```
function Chart_Weekly_Trends_Bar(DIVID, TITLE, CATEGORIES, yAxisLabel, Tooltip, ANALYSTS_NAMES, ANALYSTS_DATA) {
    var Param_CATEGORIESS = JSON.stringify(CATEGORIES);
    var data_CATEGORIESS = JSON.parse(Param_CATEGORIESS);

    var arr = [];

    for (var i = 0; i < ANALYSTS_NAMES.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = {};
        arr[i]['name'] = ANALYSTS_NAMES[i]; //Here push your series name field in your example "John, Jane etc"
        arr[i]['data'] = ANALYSTS_DATA[i]; //Here push your series name field in your example "John, Jane etc"
    }
    //arr = arr;
    var Param_arr = JSON.stringify(arr);
    var data_arr = JSON.parse(Param_arr);

    $("#" + DIVID).highcharts({
        chart: {
            type: 'column',
            height: 450,
            width: 800,
            renderTo: 'weeklypackagingtrends'
        },
        title: {
            text: TITLE
        },
        xAxis: {
            categories: data_CATEGORIESS,
            //categories: ['20-10-2015','21-10-2015'],
            tickInterval: .5,
            tickmarkPlacement: 'on',
            gridLineWidth: .5,
            min: 0,
            max: 9,
            labels: {
                style: {
                    fontSize: '9px'
                }
            }
        },
        yAxis: {
            opposite: true,
            min: 0,
            title: {
                text: yAxisLabel
            }
        },
        tooltip: {
            headerFormat: '<span style="font-size:20px">{point.key}</span><table width=150px>',
            pointFormat: '<tr><td style="color:{series.color};padding:0">{series.name}: </td>' +
                '<td style="padding:0"><b>{point.y:1f} </b></td></tr>',
            footerFormat: '</table>',
            shared: true,
            useHTML: true,
            animation: true
        },
        plotOptions: {
            column: {
                pointPadding: 0.2,
                borderWidth: 0
            }
        },
        scrollbar: {
            enabled: true
        },
        series: data_arr,
        navigation: {
            buttonOptions: {
                verticalAlign: 'bottom',
                y: -20,
                height: 30,
                theme: {
                    'stroke-width': 1,
                    stroke: 'silver',
                    r: 0,
                    states: {
                        hover: {
                            fill: '#bada55'
                        },
                        select: {
                            stroke: '#039',
                            fill: '#bada55'
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        },
        credits: {
            enabled: false
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are currently sending your data arrays as an array of strings:

```
['0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,2', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0', '0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,2,1', '0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0']
```

What you need is an array of arrays:

```
[[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,1,0,2], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,2,1,0,0,2,1], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0]]
```

Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/jlbriggs/485vxh9c/4/